# Dispose itextSharp objects

Tags: c#, compact-framework, itext

I want to dispose itextsharp document, PdfWriter, Font Color objects to be disposed explicitly. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve the same.

Comment: Either, these objects provide a **Dispose()** method or they don't. If they don't, there will be not much you can do about it.

Comment: If dispose don't exist, set the objects to null and then call garbage collection and they will be disposed

Comment: @StefanE: Still it is not working. I have created wrapper for itextsharp, which is getting disposed but making itextsharp object null is not working, even calling garbace collector.

Comment: Can you post some code? It is difficult to guess what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Agree with codymanix, need more info about the problem. Tell us what you are doing, why you want to dispose the object and what is not working. cheers

Comment: GC's are good enough these days that explicit disposal is usually (but not always) a bad idea.

Comment: @Anant, how do you know that iTextSharp "isn't getting disposed"?

Comment: @Chris: I have a compact framework application where i am using iTextSharp library. I have created wrapper for that, which is of type idisposable. And scope of that wrapper class object is local which is getting disposed after execution of function but Font, Color and other objects are remained as it is. I checked the same using.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404355.aspx

Comment: @Anant, using that profiler you're see memory being allocated and after disposing of your object its not being deallocated, right? And because of that you're assuming that its something in iTextSharp because that's the only thing you're doing? I hope I don't sound condescending, I just don't have anything to test a CF app on and that link doesn't give a lot of information on the profiler so I'm just guessing a bit. You know that `IDisposable` is only a pattern-agreement interface, right? It 100% doesn't actually do anything, its up to you to do the disposal.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked through some code (had a free couple of minutes). It looks like PdfWriter implements IDisposable (or at least IDocListener does, which if you go far enough down, PdfWriter inherits from). You should just be able to call Dispose() (or wrap it in a using statement):

```
using(PdfWriter MyWriter=PdfWriter.GetInstance(Document,Stream))
{
...
}
```

Same with most everything else (Document, etc.). Although that seems to be only with newer versions (the 4.0 version in one of my projects doesn't seem to use IDisposable for PdfWriter, etc.)